# How to disable rear window washing system on 2004 Ford Focus Turnier?

Tags: ford, focus, windshield-washer

The pipe to the rear window washing system of my 2004 Ford Focus Turnier broke at the bend of the trunk door. Until I realised this, a decent amount of washing fluid went into the roof cladding.

The last ~ 20cm seem to have already been replaced some time ago, there was a coupling that connected what I assume to be the original pipe (black, maybe silicone) to a replacement (clear, PVC?). This was secured with a zip tie, therefore I think it's not original.

Until I get this replaced, I'd like to disable the pump for the rear washing system to prevent more rain in the trunk. I didn't find a suitable entry in the "Fuses" section of the manual.

The car has been produced for the German market.

I hope my question is clear, feel free to translate it to proper english :)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can’t find a fuse just for it, just pull the power connector off the pump.  Run the pump and listen to the noise to locate it, then pull the connector off.

It is likely right below the place you fill the washer water.

Comment: Yes, I think I could do that if I put a towel under the open pipe :)

Comment: This may be more difficult than stated. The pump is likely at the very bottom of the container, and may require removing a wheel and weather guards to access. When I pulled those pumps, they were at a salvage yard and (multiple cars) were easily accessible only with the bumper off

Comment: Dang, I just changed to winter tires :-)

Comment: That is correct, I've changed my washer fluid tank recently and it takes some time. You lift up the car, remove front right wheel, unscrew the cover and then unscrew the tank. Then you'll have access to the pump. Why wouldn't you just bend and tightly secure the broken pipe?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't reach the pump like @HandyHowie suggests, an appropriately sized screw of 3 to 5 cm in length screwed into the hose should be able to prevent the fluid from coming out.

Comment: Could this lead to "overloading" the pump? I also fear that the hose might blow at another place...

Comment: @Jasper, I doubt it, unless the pump is on for hours, it should be okay.